# Submitting parent window form from child window

Tags: forms, jsp, popup, window, struts

I am displaying a popup (child windows) with some choices. Once user submits them in child windows, i am passing those values to parent window and submitting the form. the values are getting submitted to backend without any issues. however the parent window is not getting refreshed upon submitting the form.

```
function commonPopup(popup, width, height, e, top, left) {
    myWindow=window.open('about:blank', popup, 'directories=0,scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, location=0, menubar=0, status=0, toolbar=0, width=' + width + ', height=' + height + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);   
    myWindow.document.write('<HEAD>'); 
    myWindow.document.write('   <TITLE>Waiting for results</TITLE>'); 
    myWindow.document.write('</HEAD>');

}
function post_lock_unlock_value(reason,comment) {
    document.getElementById('lockReason').value = reason;
    document.getElementById('lockComment').value = comment;
    document.getElementById('triggerActionId').value='';
    document.getElementById('admRepairLock').submit();
}
<s:form name="lock" id="lock" action="my.action">
    <s:submit value="Lock Repair Profile" id="lockIndicator" name="lockIndicator"
                                                            onclick="commonPopup('lockProfile',450, 200, event,'lockRepairProfile');" cssStyle="width:200px" theme="simple"/>
</s:form>
```

in child page

```
function postback() {  
    window.opener.post_lock_unlock_value("data","data");
    self.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before closing child window refresh parent like this (add this before your `self.close()`):

```
if ( window.opener && !window.opener.closed ) {
   window.opener.location.reload();                     
   window.opener.focus();
}
```

Comment: that's trying to reload the page like when you hit F5 in your browser. My form submission is triggering the action properly. but once the action returns the refreshed page, the page is not moving. or if the action is pointing to another/different page. the window is still staying in that page.

Comment: @NitinGurram are you closing child window?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var newPartyId = $("#desc_textarea").val();
window.opener.$("#desc_textarea").val(newPartyId);
```